# Click function isn't working on iPhone browser Safari 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I implemented a click function, but it not working in Safari browser 9 on iPhone, it's working fine on other browsers. I'm using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.12.4

My code is given below:

```
$(".signup-btn").click(function() {
    $(".prelogin").fadeIn();
    $(".login-screen").fadeOut();
});
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: what console errors do you have?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".signup-btn").on('click', function() {                                         
  $(".prelogin").css({zIndex:99}).fadeIn(200);
  $(".login-screen").css({zIndex:90}).fadeOut(200);
});
```